# Формат пакета в строку

Tags: c#

У меня есть пакет с данными мене нужно высвисти его в таком виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть метод который конвертирует массив байтов  в строку.
Проблема в том что все в куче такое тяжело читать,можно форматировать стоку как на скрине сверху.

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(ba);
}
```

**Результат:**

```
02-30-00-64-F1-03-11-21-03-03-07-21-58-00-00-00-00-06-41-00-06-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-56-24-50-5F-23-57-50-22-56-5A-56-54-62-52-59-54-4F-58-00-00-00-00-00-00-DE-DE-DE-80-80-7D-82-7B-7F-00-00-96-96-3A-39-39-00-00-00-09-0F-0F-0F-F0-0F-0F-F0-F0-F0-45-00-10-51-00-08-01-10-51-00-FF-FF-FF-3F-00-00-50-01-00-FE-47-00-01-00-01-10-50-03-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
```

Как это выглядет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

@Andrew
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: т.е. проблема в том что бы разбить строку на подстроки определенной длинны или как?

Comment: @Andrew  да разбить строку на подстроки определенной длинны.

Comment: Замените `hex0.Append` на `hex0.AppendLine`, и будет вам вывод как на скрине.

Comment: Это, часом, не WinForms? Если да, то делаю ход конём: [ByteViewer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer?view=net-5.0) - компонент для просмотра байтов в hex-виде.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  Нет  использую  wpf.

Comment: Ну то есть какова конечная цель всех этих манипуляций, мы не узнаем? Зачем массив байтов переводить в строку, затем эту строку разбивать на множество других... PS: для WPF есть альтернативы ByteViewer.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Дело в том что эту строку передаю в  TextBox, Сейчас сделаю скрин.

Comment: @Vladimir измените шрифт текстбокса на `FontFamily="Consolas"`. И для WPF я писал еще такое решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302109/373567 - вдруг пригодится, да кстати, для вас же. :)

Comment: @aepot спасибо та лучше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение с использованием `StringBuilder`.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    string str = "02-30-00-64-F1-03-11-21-03-03-07-21-58-00-00-00-00-06-41-00-06-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-56-24-50-5F-23-57-50-22-56-5A-56-54-62-52-59-54-4F-58-00-00-00-00-00-00-DE-DE-DE-80-80-7D-82-7B-7F-00-00-96-96-3A-39-39-00-00-00-09-0F-0F-0F-F0-0F-0F-F0-F0-F0-45-00-10-51-00-08-01-10-51-00-FF-FF-FF-3F-00-00-50-01-00-FE-47-00-01-00-01-10-50-03-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00";
    int length = 48;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(str[i] == '-' ? ' ' : str[i]); // заменяю дефис на пробел, чтобы было удобнее читать
        if ((i + 1) % length == 0)
            sb.AppendLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb);
}
```

```
02 30 00 64 F1 03 11 21 03 03 07 21 58 00 00 00
00 06 41 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 56 24 50 5F 23 57 50 22 56 5A 56 54 62 52 59
54 4F 58 00 00 00 00 00 00 DE DE DE 80 80 7D 82
7B 7F 00 00 96 96 3A 39 39 00 00 00 09 0F 0F 0F
F0 0F 0F F0 F0 F0 45 00 10 51 00 08 01 10 51 00
FF FF FF 3F 00 00 50 01 00 FE 47 00 01 00 01 10
50 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

И еще одно, не знаю насколько быстрое, но модное решение с регулярками.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    string str = "02-30-00-64-F1-03-11-21-03-03-07-21-58-00-00-00-00-06-41-00-06-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-56-24-50-5F-23-57-50-22-56-5A-56-54-62-52-59-54-4F-58-00-00-00-00-00-00-DE-DE-DE-80-80-7D-82-7B-7F-00-00-96-96-3A-39-39-00-00-00-09-0F-0F-0F-F0-0F-0F-F0-F0-F0-45-00-10-51-00-08-01-10-51-00-FF-FF-FF-3F-00-00-50-01-00-FE-47-00-01-00-01-10-50-03-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00";
    int bytesPerLine = 16;

    string result = Regex.Replace(str, @$"((?:[^-]*-){{{bytesPerLine - 1}}}[^-]*)-", $"$1{Environment.NewLine}").Replace("-", " ");

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Вывод в консоль такой же.

Comment: Огромное  спасибо,аж глаз радует.

Comment: @Vladimir добавил еще одно решение.

Comment: Спасибо за  проделанною работу. Я очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "02-30-00-64-F1-03-11-21-03-03-07-21-58-00-00-00-00-06-41-00-06-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-56-24-50-5F-23-57-50-22-56-5A-56-54-62-52-59-54-4F-58-00-00-00-00-00-00-DE-DE-DE-80-80-7D-82-7B-7F-00-00-96-96-3A-39-39-00-00-00-09-0F-0F-0F-F0-0F-0F-F0-F0-F0-45-00-10-51-00-08-01-10-51-00-FF-FF-FF-3F-00-00-50-01-00-FE-47-00-01-00-01-10-50-03-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00";

        var len = 12;
        
        var list = Enumerable
                    .Range(0, s.Length/len)
                    .Select(i => s.Substring(i*len, len));
        
        s = string.Join("\n", list);

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

аутпут:

```
02-30-00-64-
F1-03-11-21-
03-03-07-21-
.....
```

Comment: Оно делает  разбивку,но как-то странно. Как сделать  16 хексов было в строке. Ты сделал по 4.

Comment: ну измени len. Можешь вырезать еще дефис в конце каждой строки. Я же не знаю что ты ожидаешь. Ты сказал что тебе нужно разбить строку каждые N символов - я тебе дал решение именно на это.

Comment: @Vladimir 16 замениете на 48. 3 символа на байт. Это ж очевидно должно быть.

Comment: @Andrew  Все хорошо осталось понять почему выводить подледную строку. Я думаю потому-то  в нее нету - на конце или другая проблемма.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Vladimir если в текстбокс, то вот так `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);` ну и шрифт поменяйте как я в комменте к вопросу указал.

Comment: @aepot Все гуд  осталось  исправить проблему  последний  строки.