Организация консоли вывода в приложении
В приложении необходимо организовать вывод текущей информации на экран. Что-то на подобии консоли, только без возможности ввода. В процессе работы программа будет писать туда о том, что происходит в данный момент. Предполагается, что при длительной работе, количество строк вывода может быть большим. Десятки или сотни тысяч записей.
Самым простым решением мне видится просто помещать строку в TextBox, ограничив вывод 1000 строчками. По моим подсчётам в таком случае в памяти будет крутиться не больше мегабайта данных, это ведь не большая нагрузка для современных машин?
Это приемлемое решение или же подобный вывод стоит организовывать как-то иначе?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1086544/373567 вот даже с возможностью ввода, лишнее можно выкинуть.

@aepot - немного не то. Тут прям натурально консоль из ОС создаётся. Мне же нужно просто выводить пользователю на экран информационные строки. Без возможности с его стороны что-нибудь вводить или лазить по файлам и папкам. Понятно, что можно ввод ограничить, а лишний текст зачистить. Но по факту же тут тогда всё равно получается, что в textBox.Text летят огромные строки. Или это сейчас не проблема и можно не заморачиваться? Если сделаю связный список из 1000 строк и буду постоянно удалять из начала и доставлять строку в конец, а потом всё собирать через StringBuilder, приемлемое решение будет?

Можете хоть в ItemsControl c тексблоками выводить, а его самого обернуть в ScrollViewer, тогда и строки собирать не надо будет, обычным стримридером читать. Задача то простая. И вариантов решения много.

Во https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302109/373567

@aepot большое спасибо похоже это именно то решение, которое я искал.
